# How to specify only some optional arguments when calling function in ColdFusion?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion, optional-parameters

I have a ColdFusion function "foo" which takes three args, and the second two are optional:

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="public" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="arg1" type="any" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="arg2" type="any" required="false" default="arg2" />
    <cfargument name="arg3" type="any" required="false" default="arg3" />

    ...

    <cfreturn whatever />
</cffunction>
```

I want to call foo, passing in arg1 and arg3, but ***leaving out arg2***.  I know that this is possible if I call the function using **`cfinvoke`**, but that syntax is really verbose and complicated.  I have tried these two approaches, neither works:

```
<cfset somevar=foo(1, arg3=3) /> <!--- gives syntax error --->
<cfset somevar=foo(1, arg3:3) /> <!--- gives syntax error --->
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to use named arguments throughout. You can't mix named and positional arguments as you can in some other languages.

```
<cfset somevar = foo(arg1=1, arg3=3) />
```

Answer (score 22):

Or.. you can use ArgumentCollection

In CF9 or above...

```
<cfset somevar = foo(argumentCollection={arg1=1, arg3=3})>
```

In CF8 or above...

```
<cfset args = {arg1=1, arg3=3}>
<cfset somevar = foo(argumentCollection=args)>
```

If CF7 or below...

```
<cfset args = structNew()>
<cfset args.arg1 = 1>
<cfset args.arg3 = 3>
<cfset somevar = foo(argumentCollection=args)>
```

Comment: This is how I generally prefer to do it. I'm more than likely determining which arguments to include at runtime. It's nice and easy to wrap <cfset args.foo=bar> inside a <cfif> block.

Comment: As Al implies, you should update your examples to show that a major benefit of ArgumentCollection is that it allows you to build/manipulate the structs in a flexible fashion, before sending it to the function - your current examples are just a long-winded way of using all named arguments. :)

Comment: Also worth noting is that you can mix-and-match named arguments and ArgumentCollection in a single function call.

Answer (score 2):

if you use named args you have to name the first too

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="public" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="arg1" type="any" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="arg2" type="any" required="false" default="arg2" />
    <cfargument name="arg3" type="any" required="false" default="arg3" />

    <cfreturn arg2 & " " & arg3>
</cffunction>


<cfset b = foo(arg1:1,arg3:2)>
<cfoutput>#b#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for some answers as Kip posted. Following is what I implemented. Hope it could add to our chain of possible solutions. I just added `<cfparam>` to the cffunction code:

```
<cffunction name="fn1" access="public" returntype="numeric">
   <cfargument name="arg1" type="numeric" required="true">
   <cfargument name="arg2" type="numeric" required="true">
   <cfargument name="arg3" type="query" required="false">
   <cfparam name="arguments.arg1" default=0>
   <cfparam name="arguments.arg2" default=0>
   <cfparam name="arguments.arg3" default=0>
   <cfreturn arguments.arg1 + arguments.arg2 + arguments.arg3>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#fn1(arg1=1,arg2=2)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I don't think that will work since `<cfparam>` is meant to "Tests for the existence of a parameter (that is, a variable), validates its data, and, if a default value is not assigned, optionally provides one." In this case, you label them as required, so by the time the cfparams are hit, you are guaranteed that args 1-3 exist. (If they didn't, the function call would throw an error.)

You could provide a default in the argument and make it not required, but I'm guessing in this context that that is what you are trying to avoid.